# how to convert time in unixtimestamp in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

```html
public function flag_spmlds($id)
 {
  $date = time();
  
  $myJson = "{
   'cust_id': 12,
   'label_date':".$date."
  }";
  
  $this->db->where('id',$id);
  $this->db->update('customer', ['label_by' => $myJson, 'label' => 1]); 
  echo $this->db->last_query(); 
 }
```

here i have to convert time to unixtimestamp, how to do this, can anyone please help me.

Comment: i have a data like this in table {'cust_id': 12,'label_date':1584682935}, but i don't know the lable_date in timestamp or not, first of all i don't know what is time stamp. i didn't get the clear picture of this.

Comment: Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT. so if you convert the unix timestamp i.e label_date:1584682935 in your case to human readable date form it would be "Friday, March 20, 2020 5:42:15 AM" you can learn more at https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
//Create a DateTime object.
$dateTime = new DateTime('2019-04-01');

//Format it into a Unix timestamp.
echo $dateTime->format('U');
```

And to convert number of seconds to date:

```
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $label_date);
```

To convert `unix timestamp` to human readable format.

```
$label_date = 1584682935;
$date = new DateTime("@$label_date");
echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Then this 1584682935 is not in the unixtimestamp format right sir..

Comment: It is in unix timestamp. As you mentioned you want to convert to unix timestamp so i gave First solution. But i guess you are looking for second solution. First solution is to convert `2020-03-20 05:42:15` to `1584682935`. Second is to convert `1584682935` to `2020-03-20 05:42:15`